# Need to practice quick braking - any hills nearby?

Tags: downhill, braking

So, in order to keep my rims cool enough to use while riding down hill, i've been practicing quick braking for the last 3 or so weeks, and have become confident in my ability to control my bike while moving quickly, and would like to test my braking capabilities. Is there a website or program, such as Google Earth or Google maps that will show me hills in my area? I live in sierra Vista, arizona, by the way, in case anyone happens to live here and knows a good place.

Edit:[image: sad hill] the largest hill in the area

Comment: What leads you to believe that rim heating is a problem for you that requires practice to prevent?

Comment: @jqning I've had the rim heat up enough to raise the pressure in the tire considerably. Plus, it's also just quick braking practice

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you measure the increased tire pressure? And how much was the pressure increase? Which tire was it? Or was it both?

Comment: @jqning I was keeping my weight on the back wheel, mainly using the rear brake to reserve the front for a planned stop. It started to squeak and then i reached back and touched the rim, which was hot to the touch. I took it easy for the rest of the ride, but when I stopped, I felt the tire and it felt harder than the 120psi that I inflated it to. When measured with my portable pump, it read somewhere between 140 and 145, although I have to admit I barely use the pump because of how inaccurate it can be

Comment: Maybe you took your bike out of a cold basement and took it for a ride in a significantly higher temperature outside, and was that temperature increase the cause of your higher pressure?

Comment: @stijn the bike was left outside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever I go somewhere new on my bike, I like to check [Strava's Global Heatmap](http://labs.strava.com/heatmap/#10/-110.38313/31.52489/blue/bike).

You can easily see the routes that are most common and if you drag the little yellow fella down onto a road you can see what the road is like too.

This is most useful for finding nice roads that a lot of people ride, for major climbs, look for a segment marked HC in the regular way on Strava, but you need to be logged in for that.

Comment: PS. Doesn't Sierra Vista mean something like Mountain View?

Comment: 'to view the mountain'  is the implied translation, and is pretty apt, because Sierra Vista itself is not very hilly.

Comment: Yeah, I've been looking around on the map, plenty over the border though.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can tell, but the largest Hill around here is about 200 feet over an eighth a mile or so

Comment: Mt Lemmon looks pretty good, get a bus to Tucson? Or ride it if you're game.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong. 100 feet over a mile. See edit for picture

Comment: wow, look at that. Beautiful. http://bookmanssports.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Cycling_Mt_Lemon.jpg

Comment: I'd love to, but six hours of continuous riding would most likely kill me. I ride 6-8 miles a day and a maximum of 14 miles at once. I guess it's a good goal to reach for, though.

Comment: @alex Wow, that is an awesome site! Thanks for sharing it. I'm moving to a new neighborhood in a couple months, so it's nice to see where people are riding.

Answer (score 2):

Is this a trick question?  Your map shows Car Canyon Road heading out to the botton-right.   That's 8 miles /12 km long and rises 2500 feet or 800 metres.

And there are 9 hairpin bends, just to keep you alert.

Here's a strava route  https://www.strava.com/routes/3724007

Here's a segment, showing 39 people have done it already, with a best time of 44 minutes and the slowest was 2 1/2 hours.   https://www.strava.com/segments/1618815

Comment: This segment suggests it ain't paved. https://www.strava.com/segments/6868676

Comment: I suggested, downright stated, that I don't know of any programs to find routes or hills.

Comment: pah, call that a hill?

Comment: @peteH Tthe point was OP asked about programs to find hills nearby.  I used google maps and strava to see a non-flat area really close to the area in the screenshot.   IE if you were standing on the blue line, you couldn't miss a 2500 foot hill 12 miles away.

Comment: @alex Fair call - paved wasn't a requirement of the original question though.

Comment: @Hellreaver I used google maps, and then I used strava.  Both are websites rather than applications though.